# Ionic/Cordova: iframe from specific page goes always fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework

I've implemented an iframe in my Ionic/Cordova application, so that the status bar and menu bar remain in the view.

The app loads a page from my own server, and shows this page into an iframe. Everything works as expected. But when the user hits a button on this page, which redirects him to www.sofort.com/... (payment provider), the iframe goes fullscreen and everything from Ionic is not available anymore.

How can I require the iframe to stay in the ion-view? I tested another website (redirection) and everything worked as expected (the redirection stayed in the iframe).

The redirect is executed with a `form action="http://www.sofort.com/...`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've got it. There was a problem with a javascript file from www.sofort.com, because the page wants to redirect on `top-level-navigation` level.

The solution is to add the [HTML5 attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) `sandbox` to the `iframe`, and allow everything except `top-level-navigation`. Then everything would stay inside the iframe.

So the `iframe` would looke like:

```
<iframe src="http://www.domain.com" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts"></iframe>
```